# Issues with passing state between two separate components using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks, setstate

So my issue is that I’m basically trying to pass the data that I have fetched from an API on my Home page, which is fetched and stored in the ‘geo’  variable upon pressing the submit button, and pass it onto the Maps page (accessed by pressing the Maps button after a postcode has been submitted), which will then use the latitude and longitude from ’geo’ (geo.result.latitude/longitude) to fetch from another API upon loading and display that data on the page. However, I’m having an issue with understanding how to pass state (or the values within the geo variable) between the two components/pages (Home and Maps) using hooks. I’m reasonably new to React, and very new to Hooks, so my understanding is very basic at the moment. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Home.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = () => {

  const [postCode, setPostcode] = useState({

    pCode: ''

  })

  const [geo, setGeo] = useState([])

  const fetchRequest = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch(`https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/${postCode.pCode}`)

      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setGeo(res))

    console.log(geo)

  }, [{ ...postCode }])

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setPostcode({ ...postCode, pCode: e.target.value })
    console.log(postCode)

  }

  return <section >

    <div className='container'>

      <form className="form" onSubmit={fetchRequest}>
        <input className="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" onChange={handleChange} />
        < button>submit</button>
        <Link className='button' to={{
          pathname: '/maps'
        }}>Map

        </Link>
      </form>

    </div>

  </section>

}

export default Home
```

Maps.js

```
const Maps = () => {

  const [events, setEvents] = useState([])

  const fetchRequest = useCallback(() => {

    fetch(`https://api.list.co.uk/v1/events?near=${viewport.latitude},${viewport.longitude}/10`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setEvents(res))


  }, [{ ...viewport }])

  useEffect(() => {

    fetch(`https://api.list.co.uk/v1/events?near=${geo.result.latitude},${geo.result.longitude}/10`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setEvents(res))

    return () => console.log('Unmounting component')

  }, [])

  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: '100vw',
    height: '100vh',
    latitude: 51.45523,
    longitude: -2.59665,
    zoom: 13.5

  })

  if (events.length === 0) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return <div>
    <ReactMapGL mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN}
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/dredizzle/ck3owxclr138a1cqnzupab2hc"
      {...viewport}
      onViewportChange={viewport => {
        setViewport(viewport)
      }}
      onClick={
        fetchRequest
      }

    >

      {events.map(event => (
        <Popup
          key={event.event_id}
          latitude={event.schedules[0].place.lat}
          longitude={event.schedules[0].place.lng}
        >
        </Popup>
      ))}


      {/* <Popup latitude={51.45523} longitude={-2.59665}>
        <div>event here</div>
      </Popup> */}
      <GeolocateControl
        positionOptions={{ enableHighAccuracy: true }}
        trackUserLocation={false}
      />
    </ReactMapGL>
  </div>
}

export default Maps
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Maps component, I think you're overwriting the value of `events` when you repeat this line:

`const [events, setEvents] = useState([])`

You should just be able to reference `this.state.events` within the Maps component, and use `this.setState()` within Maps to add data to the `events` array from within the component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I think you either didn't read the question properly or you misunderstood what I was asking :). I don't have any issues with events or setting state of events, I'm simply trying to pass the state of the 'geo' variable from the Home component/page to the Maps component/page, and then using the geo variable to fetch data from the API on load. I can do this using standard React, but I'm unsure how to do this using React Hooks. Thanks